# how to define types as interfaces in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have many parts in my code where I define specific types like this:

`function foo (state: "open" | "closed") { ... }`

I want to know if there is a way to define that type like interfaces. something like:

`type State: "open" | "closed";`

so I can use it in a clearer way:

`function foo (state: State) { ... }`

Comment: Yes, you want a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) of the form `type State = "open" | "closed"`.

Comment: it works~ thanks, Sir~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `type`. You are almost there:

```
type State = "open" | "closed";

function foo (state: State) { console.log(state); }
foo("open"); 
foo("openx"); //Error
foo("closed");
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=15&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oCID2kB2aoB90BjAGwwGcIATNAbgFgAoJgMwFdsjgBLDbKFhgxQAFOQRIAXLAkQAlFADeUIn3IYSEAHRkA5mNlzaUAL6shIzDjRHzGS1gjYAHjYaNB9tKQrU3TJiA)

Comment: it works just nicely. thanks~